# How do I prevent this HTML text from wrapping?

Tags: html

I have created a custom HTML email signature that renders fine in my Apple Mail client

[image: What I show in my preview window]

but when bringing it into MS Outlook on a PC it renders with unintended line breaks and an enlarged image.

[image]

What could be causing the line to break in Outlook and not Apple Mail? Is there a "safeguard" parameter of some sort I could add to make it compatible with both? I'm really new to HTML.

```html
<html>
<STYLE>
  A {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
</STYLE>

<body>
  <table width="500%" height="48" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td style="padding:0 8px 0 0;vertical-align: middle;"><img alt="TETON Sports" style="width:69px; height: 50px;" src="https://tetonsports.imagerelay.com/ql/015ce962f5e74fbfb86292c6b6e60ea8/email-icon-01.png">
            </td>
            <td style="font-size:1em;padding:0 0 0 0;vertical-align: top;" valign="top">
              <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="line-height: 1.4;font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-size:14px;color: #000001;">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#000001;">
                      TETON Sports
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td style="padding: 0px 0;">
                    <div style="color:#000001;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;">
                      <b> Josh Jorgensen </b>
                      <span style="color:#FF9E18;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;"> <b>//</b> </span>
                      <span style="color:#54565A;font-family:Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;"> <i>Photographer</i> </span>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <span style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#54565A;" <span><i>josh@tetonsports.com</i></span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <br>
            <br>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <br style=“ line-height:200px;”>
        <div style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#ffffff;">
          ...
        </div>
        <span> </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Validate your HTML. For example you have a type span here: `<span style="font: 1.0em Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;color:#54565A;" <span><i>josh@tetonsports.com</i></span>
                 `

Comment: Also you should change all the height and widths to css styles like you do in some of the attributes. Lastly you can add `white-space: nowrap;` to the container and remove whitespace around the <b> tags in your name

Comment: it's ok on my pc, how do you add the signature?

Answer (score 1):

In your table, you are setting your table's width to `500%`, while the image's width is in pixels.

So when your window is smaller, your entire table gets smaller but your image stays the same size, eating up space from the text section.

Consider being consistent across the board, and using either only percentages or only pixels for your widths.